# Ignite problem when trying to generate PCFs on Innsbruck

Tags: ignite, guidewire

After generating a proper PolicyCenter Innsbruck .jar file (C:/Guidewire/policycenter/modules/configuration/build/libs/pc-configuration-50.9.0.jar) I'm trying to generate the page objects following the rules found here: https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/testing/202310/ui/gw-ui/topics/c_running_ignite.html

But I get this error, in which it seems ignite didn't found a .jar inside the pc-configuration-50.9.0.jar:

```
npx ignite --pcfOption pc --task generateGTUIPageObjectFiles --projectRootLocation "ui/pages/gw/generated/policycenter/" --pcfLocation "C:/Guidewire/policycenter/modules/configuration/build/libs/pc-configuration-50.9.0.jar"

-------------------------------------------------------------------
Running Ignite command:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Ignite version= 2023.10.0
PCF Jar Location= C:/Guidewire/policycenter/modules/configuration/build/libs/pc-configuration-50.9.0.jar
Task Type= generateGTUIPageObjectFiles
Page Object Output Location= ui/pages/gw/generated/policycenter/pages
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: libsWithPcfs\pc-configuration-10.0.3.jar
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:85)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:103)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:108)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:53)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileAttributeViews$Basic.readAttributes(WindowsFileAttributeViews.java:38)
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:198)
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1764)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$Source.get(ZipFile.java:1414)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.<init>(ZipFile.java:742)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile$CleanableResource.get(ZipFile.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:257)
        at java.base/java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:186)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:348)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:319)
        at java.base/java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:258)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.utils.PcfUtils.printPCFVersion(PcfUtils.java:227)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.utils.PcfUtils.setupPcfUtils(PcfUtils.java:147)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.utils.PcfUtils.buildPcfProgramList(PcfUtils.java:175)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.PCFOperation.initialiseConfiguration(PCFOperation.java:22)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.PCFOperation.<init>(PCFOperation.java:18)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.IgniteService.performPCFOperation(IgniteService.java:65)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.IgniteService.main(IgniteService.java:33)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pcftest.Admin
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:594)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.utils.PcfUtils.loadPcfClass(PcfUtils.java:61)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.utils.PcfUtils.getRootPcfClasses(PcfUtils.java:111)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.utils.PcfUtils.buildPcfProgramList(PcfUtils.java:179)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.PCFOperation.initialiseConfiguration(PCFOperation.java:22)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.PCFOperation.<init>(PCFOperation.java:18)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.IgniteService.performPCFOperation(IgniteService.java:65)
        at com.gw.ptf.mcg.IgniteService.main(IgniteService.java:33)
```

So, whats' wrong? The pc-configuration-50.9.0.jar was created after a fresh gwb clean && gwb build, no errors and PolicyCenter is currently happy running on my laptop...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer so I'll share this as a comment.  Is this a fresh install of the GT:UI tooling?  One common issue is trying to upgrade GT components "in place" via a merge.  If this is an upgrade, try starting from a clean install.

If that doesn't help you then I'd suggest opening a case with Guidewire Support since this appears to be a product issue.

Comment: It came from a fresh Bitbucket install by Guidewire... And yes I already opened a case, I think the same as you

Answer (score 0):

This looks like Ignite is unable to locate a dependency jar file. To address this you have 2 options:

1.) Build an uber jar (one that contains all dependencies)
2.) Get the dependent jar files deployed to your Ignite nodes and remove
any path references for the dependent jar file.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The problem here is that the .jar is missing. It can't be found on the repo...

Answer (score 0):

Case closed. I got assistance from GW and we start over all the process and it was ok, so we think the issue would came from the process of moving directories and files, considering this is a process to upgrade from Elysian to Innsbruck